# Vaadin frontend folder not found

Tags: java, vaadin, vaadin-flow

I have a rather strange problem.
I have setup my project with multiple modules (parent pom) and my Vaadin webapp is in the UI module. I am loading a theme when I am starting the app. (see below)

```
@SpringBootApplication
@Theme(value = "myVaadinApp")
@PWA(name = "MyVaadinApp", shortName = "MyVaadinApp", offlineResources = {"images/logo.png"})
public class Application extends SpringBootServletInitializer implements AppShellConfigurator {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String port = System.getenv().getOrDefault("PORT", "8080");
        SpringApplication app = new SpringApplication(Application.class);
        app.setDefaultProperties(Collections.singletonMap("server.port", port));
        app.run(args);
    }
}
```

This Theme is in a folder called `frontend`. The funny thing is, I need a `./frontend` folder in my top level project folder, if not, the app doesn't start and I get this error below:

```
2021-09-18 11:01:53.455 ERROR 25150 --- [nio-8080-exec-6] o.a.c.c.C.[.[.[/].[dispatcherServlet]    : Servlet.service() for servlet [dispatcherServlet] in context with path [] threw exception [com.vaadin.flow.server.ServiceException: java.lang.IllegalStateException: com.vaadin.flow.server.ExecutionFailedException: Discovered @Theme annotation with theme name 'myVaadinApp', but could not find the theme directory in the project or available as a jar dependency. Check if you forgot to create the folder under '/home/raptox/myVaadinApp/./frontend/themes' or have mistyped the theme or folder name for 'myVaadinApp'.] with root cause

com.vaadin.flow.server.ExecutionFailedException: Discovered @Theme annotation with theme name 'myVaadinApp', but could not find the theme directory in the project or available as a jar dependency. Check if you forgot to create the folder under '/home/raptox/myVaadinApp/./frontend/themes' or have mistyped the theme or folder name for 'myVaadinApp'.
    at com.vaadin.flow.server.frontend.TaskUpdateThemeImport.verifyThemeDirectoryExistence(TaskUpdateThemeImport.java:120) ~[flow-server-8.0.0.beta3.jar:8.0.0.beta3]
    at com.vaadin.flow.server.frontend.TaskUpdateThemeImport.execute(TaskUpdateThemeImport.java:79) ~[flow-server-8.0.0.beta3.jar:8.0.0.beta3]
    at com.vaadin.flow.server.frontend.NodeTasks.execute(NodeTasks.java:766) ~[flow-server-8.0.0.beta3.jar:8.0.0.beta3]
    at com.vaadin.base.devserver.startup.DevModeInitializer.runNodeTasks(DevModeInitializer.java:499) ~[vaadin-dev-server-8.0.0.beta3.jar:na]
    at com.vaadin.base.devserver.startup.DevModeInitializer.lambda$initDevModeHandler$0(DevModeInitializer.java:387) ~[vaadin-dev-server-8.0.0.beta3.jar:na]
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture$AsyncRun.run$$$capture(CompletableFuture.java:1736) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture$AsyncRun.run(CompletableFuture.java) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture$AsyncRun.exec(CompletableFuture.java:1728) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinTask.doExec$$$capture(ForkJoinTask.java:290) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinTask.doExec(ForkJoinTask.java) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinPool$WorkQueue.topLevelExec(ForkJoinPool.java:1020) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinPool.scan(ForkJoinPool.java:1656) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinPool.runWorker(ForkJoinPool.java:1594) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinWorkerThread.run(ForkJoinWorkerThread.java:183) ~[na:na]
```

However, the CSS in the `./frontend` folder doesn't get taken into account. I need a `./ui/frontend` folder for the CSS to get used. So now I have 2 **frontend** folders laying around in my project ...

Comment: What version of Vaadin are you using? The theme should be in the folder /frontend/themes

Comment: I am using Vaadin Flow v21

Comment: And your theme is in frontend/themes/myVaadinApp

Comment: So yes, I need to have 2 themes, one in frontend/themes/myVaadinApp and one in ui/frontend/themes/myVaadinApp. So it is duplicated. But actually only the one in the ui/ is being used and the other one is needed so that the server can start. I would like to have it only once ...

Comment: Can you share your project? Or create a minimal reproducible example?